# How can i read the table name while showing tables from database php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

Hi Am trying to read the table name from the dropdown but am unable give the name option name. Here is my code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Enter number of titles:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select>
                  <?php 
                     include 'config.php';
                     $query="show tables";
                     $result_query=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_query))
                       {
                          echo "<option>$row[0]</option>";
                       }
                  ?>
                 </select>
              </div>
        </div>
```

How can I give the option value or name as there are 10 tables I need to read the table name once the table is selected

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
echo "<option>$row[0]</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>";
```

Comment: Yaa I got it sorry for question but how can I store it in variable

Comment: in PHP or JS? in PHP you must use FORM tag and set attr "name" to SELECT tag(<select name="table">)